# jQuery/JavaScript adding event triggers in OOP

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I use the following structure to set out my objects/classes in JavaScript:

```
SelectUser = function(instanceID) {
    this._instanceID = instanceID;

    // Initialize
    this.initialize();
}

SelectUser.prototype = {
    initialize: function () {
        ...
    },

    update(userID) {
        $('#hidden-field-' + this._instanceID).val(userID);
    }
}
```

This allows me to say:

```
$selectUser = new SelectUser(1);
```

Outside of the `SelectUser` object I need to execute some different code (per instance of `SelectUser`) each time the value of the hidden field is changed.  My first idea was to try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $selectUser = new SelectUser(1);
        $selectUser2 = new SelectUser(2);

        $('#hidden-field-1').change(function () {
            alert('Something');
        });

        $('#hidden-field-2').change(function () {
            alert('Something else');
        });
    });
</script>
```

However the alert is not triggered.  My next thought was to add an event trigger on my update function/method within the `SelectUser` object/class.  Then I can subscribe to this event per each instance and execute some different code.

How do I do this?  I've been using JavaScript for years but I'm fairly new to jQuery and OOP in JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) doesn't fire the `change` event since you're changing it programmatically, you can however trigger the event yourself so all the handlers bound for it run.  To do that, use [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/), like this:

```
$('#hidden-field-' + this._instanceID).val(userID).change();
```

To trigger events you have a few options, [`.trigger('change')`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) triggers it *and* bubbles up ([`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) without any arguments is just a shortcut for this).  Then there's also [`.triggerHandler('change')`](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/) if you just want to trigger event handlers *directly* on the element but not have it bubble or do the native action....but 99% of the time you're after [`.trigger('change')`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) or the [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) shortcut.